# jenkins job DSL を eclipse 上で、補完機能を使いながら編集したい

Tags: eclipse, jenkins, groovy

jenkins job DSL のスクリプトを作成する際に、 eclipse で補完を行いながら編集したいと思いました。

DSL 自体は groovy で記述されるので、 groovy-eclipse でこれを実現できると考えました。groovy-eclipse をインストールし、プロジェクトを作成、そのなかで groovy スクリプトを作成し、 helloWorld を記述・実行してみた状態です。

目的を達成するには、この状態から、 jenkins job DSL の定義を、どうにかして読み込まないといけないのだと考えているのですが、これはどうやったら実現できますでしょうか。

groovy についての知識は、コンソール上で helloWorld を昔書いたぐらいの知識です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse上で、ということですが、そこに強い縛りも無いようにも読めました。
特に制約が無いのであれば、IntelliJを使用してみてはどうでしょうか。
こちらであればオフィシャルサポートも期待できるのではないかと思います。

https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/blob/master/docs/IDE-Support.md

文中に登場するリンク[GroovyDSL](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/GRVY/Scripting+IDE+for+DSL+awareness)について、画面キャプチャ付きで解説されている方がいらっしゃいましたので、こちらを参照すると雰囲気がつかめるかと思います。

- [GroovyDSL と IntelliJ IDEA - 倭マン's BLOG](http://waman.hatenablog.com/entry/20110412/1302570326)

コンテンツ・アシスト(content assist)というのがいわゆる補完機能です。